# Erro 404 apache Tomcat

Tags: java, web-service, apache, rest, tomcat

sou novo no que se diz respeito a web services, no entanto ultimamente peguei para desenvolver o meu, no entanto não consigo nem fazer um hello world devido a um erro que o Tomcat está me retornando, ele simplesmente não encontra a URL, podem me ajudar?

```
package Login;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Matheus
 */
@Path("/Teste")
public class Teste {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of Teste
     */
    public Teste() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of Login.Teste
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getText() {
        //TODO return proper representation object
        return "ola";
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of Teste
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void putText(String content) {
    }
}
```

O URL da home é http://localhost:8080/Projeto, essa pagina é encontrada facilmente, no entanto quando vou acessar o URL  http://localhost:8080/Projeto/Teste que é para retornar um "olá" ele simplesmente retorna um erro 404 de pagina não encontrada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa dar *muito mais* detalhes para que alguém entenda o seu problema. Sugiro ler as seções da ajuda: [Como Fazer uma Pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa ter uma classe que configure a aplicação.

Coloque o seguinte código:

```
package login;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {}
```

Com isso funcionou sem problemas aqui no Glassfish.

O caminho para acessar a página será:

```
http://localhost:8080/Projeto/api/Teste
```

Outra coisa importante, os nomes de pacotes devem começar com letra minúscula, por isso mudei para `login`.

Comment: Amigo, preciso criar uma classe para colocar esse código? Ou é apenas colar isso na classe acima?

Comment: Precisa criar uma classe no pacote login com o nome ApplicationConfig e colar esse código.

Comment: Amigo, tentei fazer essas alterações aqui e continua retornando o código 404.

Comment: Comigo essa alternativa não surtiu efeito @prmottajr

Comment: @TiagoFerezin qual erro acontece aí?

Comment: @prmottajr o meu intecept esta disparando o erro